# LVM snapshot merge is slow and somethims gets stuck

Tags: partitioning, performance, lvm, snapshot

I am having some issues related to lvm snapshot merge.

When running

```
lvconvert --merge <snasphot>
```

on ubuntu 14.04.6 (kernel 3.19.0-80-generic) everything worked fine.
Lvm version is:

```
  LVM version:     2.02.98(2) (2012-10-15)
  Library version: 1.02.77 (2012-10-15)
  Driver version:  4.29.0
```

Running the same command on ubuntu 18.04.4 (kernel 4.15.0-76-generic) is much slower (can take few hours).
Lvm version is:

```
 LVM version:     2.02.176(2) (2017-11-03)
 Library version: 1.02.145 (2017-11-03)
 Driver version:  4.37.0
```

Also,
there are sometimes when the merge gets stuck, when looking on

```
dmestup status <lvm-base>
```

I can see that the merge is stuck.
The output is

```
0 8388608 snapshot-merge 16/2097152 16
```

and there is no change, no progress and the snapshot is not merged.

Any ideas what could be the problem?